# Is Open Website Feature, Available in Visual Studio For MAC?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have been a seasoned .Net + Azure developer with master over all short-cuts & popular extensions available. I use Visual Studio even for Node Js development. I am trying to make a switch to MAC which seems impossible :-(

> Quite surprised that even basic options like Open WebSite has been
>   missing in Visual Studio For MAC.
>
> Has any of expert community member here, tried switching to VS for MAC and
>   found a way to open website written in Angular or React?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac is a different product. So either you wait or use other tools such as Visual Studio Code.

Comment: No it doesn't appear to be available. This is really an Alpha product. The bugs in the text editor are crazy too. Yes it *should* be the same product. If it's 'Visual Studio' it's Visual Studio. If it was "Microsoft IDE for Mac" then we wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Microsoft's website](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) states, Visual Studio for Mac is a completely new IDE which needs a lot of development before you should use it for your real projects.

I would highly recommend to run a virtual Windows machine (or even Windows itself) on your Mac. 
You could try though, to use Visual Studio Code with AngularJS on your Mac.

Edit 08.03.2018: by now Microsoft has done a lot for Visual Studio Mac. What you want will probably work.

Comment: As of today, 8/30/19, I am still unable to open a website via Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Today is 2020 dec, I still cannot find the website feature in vs Mac. But it's reasonable because .net based website is run in Windows server. It doesn’t make sense to build in mac but execute in windows.